# How to get reference of activity object?

Tags: android

I want to show a messageBox or notification when connection lost in Static Database class.
But I can't use getApplicationContext() as the class is static and I tried to call other class called notification but I have an error. So How could I pass activity object to my new class ?

Comment: Show us some code of what you've tried, that's the easiest way for people to spot what you've done wrong. And please, try to use some punctuation when writing. It makes it a lot easier to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you doing it's wrong. You should pass a context each time when you call your static methods.

However you can have a static Context property in that class, and you could put in your current context before calling for a method. But this is bad practice! Don't do it!

Comment: Why is it bad practice? for example in subclass of Application a Singlton Database Helper is created and a reference to Application is passed to. future call to other methods of database helper which require access to context may use that reference. Would you please let me know why it is bad practice while it helps us writing cleaner code

Comment: @anonim.developer It's bad practice because maintaining a static reference to a Context can cause memory leaks. See here: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: @f20k, your reference does recommend using application-context as I said. So what's wrong with my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a "static DB class" that works with the UI in the fashion you are seeking. For any call that may fail, have an `Activity` (or possibly other `Context`) be passed in as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the activity context in the constructor of your class. Code would help though.